# attempt to index global 'torch' (a nil value)

Tags: lua, torch, zerobrane

When I run a simple piece of code `a = torch.Tensor(5,3)` in `ZeroBraneStudio`, I receive the following error:

`attempt to index global 'torch' (a nil value)`

Does this mean that `ZeroBraneStudio` does not recognize `Torch`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you select Torch as the interpreter (`Project | Lua Interpreter | Torch-7`) and configure the path to your th or luajit executable from torch (as described in [this post](http://notebook.kulchenko.com/zerobrane/torch-debugging-with-zerobrane-studio)).